# getting output from TextCalendar as string

Tags: python, calendar

I'm currently working on a little project that's about dates.
It's already completed and now I'm working on GUI.
Is there any way to get an output from calendar.TextCalendar().prmonth(x , y) function as a string to store it in variable?

Answer (score 0):

The [prmonth](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.TextCalendar.prmonth) method prints the output of [formatmonth](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.TextCalendar.formatmonth). So just do:

```
    calendar.TextCalendar().formatmonth(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I guess I should sleep more. How could I miss it =\